# Spring Sleuth not working for SOAP outgoing calls (out-of-the-box)

Tags: java, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm trying to set up the following Spring Sleuth configuration to propagate remote fields (HTTP request headers) across the projects out-of-the-box:

```
sleuth:
  async:
    enabled: true
  baggage:
    remote-fields:
      - Caller-Id
```

For the outgoing Rest calls, it's working fine:

`Request headers: {Accept=[application/json; distances], Authorization=[Bearer ...], X-B3-TraceId=[3f3f61757851d371], X-B3-SpanId=[3f3f61757851d371], X-B3-Sampled=[1],` **`caller-id=[value]`**`}`

However, it's not true for the SOAP outgoing calls:

`SOAP Headers - {Authorization=[Bearer...]}`

We're using Feign as Rest client and jaxws-spring for SOAP.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.revinate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sleuth can propagate x-b3-* header automatically only to restTemplate, webClient and feign.

what httpclient are you using to make SOAP-calls?

Comment: It would be better if you asked questions in comments, not in your answer. It's the little improvement, but in general everything looks good